# Finding 1925 Catholic baptism record from Plymouth, Massachusetts, USA

Tags: baptism-records, 1920s, massachusetts, catholic-church

I'm searching for a baptism record for a person born in Plymouth, Massachusetts, in 1925.

The denomination is Catholic.

The name of both parents is known.

From the following link I couldn't find any relevant information,

> https://ldsgenealogy.com/MA/Plymouth-County-Church-Records.htm

The only Catholic entry is

[Baptisms of Sacred Heart Catholic Church, Brockton, MA, 1908-1990](https://ldsgenealogy.com/cgi-bin/libraries.cgi?7695_Baptisms_of_Sacred_Heart_Catholic_Church,_Brockton,_MA,_1908-1990)

but then, I don't know if this is in any way related with Plymouth (Town).

Besides, my Ancestry two-week free trial expired long time ago!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many online collections of Roman Catholic records do not include "recent" records. A better way to proceed might be to try to identify the parish and contact them for help, since you are looking for a specific person and record.

Google search using terms: *catholic diocese plymouth massachusetts* 
Results include a number of relevant parish websites

[Diocese of Boston lists](https://www.bostoncatholic.org/Parishes-And-People/Default.aspx) 4 churches in Plymouth today:
Saint Bonaventure (established 1950), Saint Kateri Tekakwitha (established 1982), Saint Mary (established 1915), Saint Peter (established 1876)

As noted, only 2 of these churches were in existence in 1925 and could be queried (contact info on the diocese and parish websites). Perhaps comparing church addresses and the home address of the family you are interested in would narrow it down further.

The St. Peter's Parish, Plymouth MA [history page](https://www.stpetersplymouth.com/Parish-History) describes the founding of the 1st RC church in Plymouth:

> With the laying of the cornerstone of St. Peter’s Church in Plymouth
>   on July 4, 1873, a new era began for the Catholics in the southeastern
>   section of the Diocese of Boston.  The construction of the parish
>   church assured Catholics scattered throughout the area of Plymouth,
>   Carver, Plympton, Kingston, Duxbury, Hanson and Marshfield that they
>   would have a church wherein they could attend Mass.  Prior to this,
>   the earliest settlers who wished to attend Mass had to go to Sandwich
>   to the Mother Church of the geographical section from Provincetown to
>   Scituate and Hanover.  ...

Comment: @LuisTavares Records that are newer than 100 years old may indeed be too recent to be hosted online.  For example, AmericanAncestors.org has an ongoing project Massachusetts: Roman Catholic Archdiocese of Boston Records, 1789-1920. St. Peter (Plymouth) Baptisms to 1900 were added in January 2019. https://dbnews.americanancestors.org/2019/01/11/new-browsable-catholic-records-from-peabody-plymouth-and-roxbury/

Comment: 70 years may not seem recent (hence the quotes), but privacy restrictions (which vary between jurisdictictions) can go to 100 years. Or there might licensing restrictions, to ensure some entity gets a fee for access, When you consider the sheer volume of what records are out there, it's also unsurprising that not everything is online (yet).

Comment: I'm re-accepting this question. Now, I undestand why there aren't more Catholic records online, https://www.archbalt.org/vatican-letter-directs-bishops-to-keep-parish-records-from-mormons/